# Cloudformation circular dependency confusion

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm totally lost on this circular dependency issue with Cloudformation. I wrote this template, and it works great with run from the CLI, but when I try to launch it from the browser as a Stack, I get this circular dependency issue.

Can someone tell me where the dependency is coming from ?

This is the Error I get

```
Circular dependency between resources: [VehiclesLambda, HelloAPI, AuthorizerFuncPerm]
```

Here is my template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Yes you can use SAM to create an Authorizer
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Type: String
    Default: dev
Outputs:
  ExampleAPIUrl:
    Value: !Sub "https://${HelloAPI}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${Environment}/"
Resources:
  HelloAPI:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Sub ${Environment}
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        info:
          title:
            Ref: AWS::StackName
        securityDefinitions:
          test-authorizer:
            type: apiKey
            name: Authorization
            in: header
            x-amazon-apigateway-authtype: custom
            x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
              type: token
              authorizerUri:
                Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${AuthorizerFunc.Arn}/invocations
              authorizerResultTtlInSeconds: 5
        paths:
          /vehicles:
            get:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: POST
                type: aws_proxy
                uri:
                  !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${VehiclesLambda.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}
              security:
                - test-authorizer: []
  VehiclesLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs4.3 
      CodeUri: 's3://companyrentalaws/vehicles.zip'
      MemorySize: 128 
      Timeout: 30
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Events:
        MyEndpoint:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /vehicles
            Method: GET
            RestApiId:
              Ref: HelloAPI
  AuthorizerFunc:
      Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
      Properties:
        Handler: authorizer.authorizer
        Runtime: nodejs4.3
        CodeUri: 's3://companyrentalaws/authorizer.zip'
  AuthorizerFuncPerm:
      Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
      DependsOn:
        - HelloAPI
        - AuthorizerFunc
      Properties:
        Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
        FunctionName:
          Ref: AuthorizerFunc
        Principal: apigateway.amazonaws.com
```

Sorry for posting so much code, but didn't want to leave anything out.

Comment: Why do you need DependsOn: - HelloAPI for AuthorizerFuncPerm?

Comment: I just tried commenting out out the DependOn statement, didn't seem to help.  I'm sort of wondering if it has something to do with the policies ?

Comment: I did remove the statement "Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31" from the transform, and it will run, but it makes a bunch of ChangeSets, still not sure what causes that.

Comment: post another question to get information about that and add your answer here, how you solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

VehiclesLambda has a property RestApiId which refs HelloAPI.

```
            RestApiId:
              Ref: HelloAPI
```

HelloAPI Fn:GetAttr's VehiclesLambda's Arn

```
!Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${VehiclesLambda.Arn}/invocations
```

There is your circular dependency.